# What are the advantages and disadvantages between gas, liquid and solid fuel?

Tags: cooking, stoves, fuel

It seems you can get fuel for stoves in either gas form (butane, propane, etc.) liquid (methylated spirit) or solid fuel tablets.

What are the particular advantages and disadvantages with each format, and when might you use one over the other?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Note on boiling and stove weights, obviously there are dozens of stoves out there for every fuel.  I'm just estimating based on commonly used stoves.

**Petroleum, Gas, White Gas, other liquid petrol products**
Stove weight:  12+ oz (340+ g)
Water Boil per 100g fuel (rough):  5 to 6L
Good:

- Works below freezing
- incredibly good heat
- fuel is easy to come by
- fuel energy density is high enough so that just the fuel in the tank is enough for a few days, so no need to bring extra fuel cans.

Bad:

- Heavy
- high maintenance
- must pack out fuel cans
- more likely to go boom

**Alcohol (liquid)**
Stove weight:  0.25 for a [DIY Stove](http://jwbasecamp.com/Articles/SuperCat/index.html) (7.1g)
Good:

- Minimal equipment needed
- good for ultralight setups
- almost impossible to make it go boom
- very easy to light/use
- In a pinch you can use a wide variety of fuels making resupply a non-issue
- Ridiculously cheap gear.  My entire kit cost $5 and I got a beer out of it.

Bad:

- Poor effective heat/weight of the fuel (due to burn rate, but still good for ultralight due to minimal gear need)
- Won't work as well in extreme cold.  It requires extra gear, like a preheater, as shown in this [Trangia video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWw8hppj94g&feature=player_embedded).  Here's some extra testing from another hiker [here](http://www.backpackinglight.com/cgi-bin/backpackinglight/forums/thread_display.html?forum_thread_id=18427&nid=151623).  Alcohol is hard to light in deep cold and it's extremely hard/nigh impossible to boil water with it in sub freezing temps.
- Pretty finicky to use, at least with a DIY setup.
- In bright light it is sometimes easy to miss the flame and not realize it is still lit, creating a possible hazard.
- Fuel hard to find in some parts of the world, [such as Russia](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/22462/566)

**Butane, Propane, Isobutane (pressurized gas)**
Stove weight:  3 to 5oz (85 to 142g)
Water Boil per 100g fuel (rough):  7 to 8L
Good:

- good heat
- lightweight stove options available
- Wind, what wind?  I've successfully boiled water in near freezing temps and high winds just by huddling over my [MSR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000A8C5QE) to dampen the wind (which is a pretty poor wind screen).

Bad:

- Must carry multiple canisters for long trips
- canisters can discharge while packed if not packed carefully
- must pack out fuel cans
- use of a heat shield requires very special care to avoid canister explosion (however a heat shield is a nice to have instead of a must have in most conditions with this setup)

Note:  Sometimes it will work below freezing, sometimes it won't.  It's a function of how it's handled.  Also has issues at altitude.  That's because these work by the liquid inside boiling and releasing gas out the top of the canister which doesn't work as well at lower pressure or temperature.  Some designs address this by inverting the canister.

**Hexamine (solid fuel)**
Stove weight:  <1 oz (<28g)
Good:

- Super lightweight
- easy to get at stops and small towns
- boils water well

Bad:

- Not very good for other cooking (due to smell)
- soots pots with this sticky goo
- contaminates everything if not handled very carefully.
- hard to start and will not heat well in wind without an excellent wind screen

Comment: Alcohol doesn't burn well below freezing?  I think the Swedish folks who make [Trangia](http://www.trangia.se/english) stoves would be surprised to hear that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen -- Thank you for the feedback.  That was based on my own personal experience.  I have updated it with some more resources, including the one you gave.

Comment: Ps. The [Trangia FAQ](http://www.trangia.se/english/2937.faq.html) says their spirit burner "works even at severe cold (below -10 degrees Celsius) if used together with the winter attachment" (priming pan). Actually, I'm pretty sure I've used them even in colder weather without one; a handy trick is to close the lid of the burner after filling it (it's liquid-proof) and warm it under your clothes for a while.

Comment: (Pps. While Googling, I found [this blog article on the Trangia 27](http://adventuresinstoving.blogspot.com/2011/11/stove-of-week-trangia-27.html); it's not directly relevant to the issue at hand, but I liked it too much not to include it here.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen -- Thank you for the extra research

Comment: "Pretty finicky to use, at least with a DIY setup" - I'd disagree with that. My $2, 2.4 ounce cat stoves work every time, completely trouble-free. The mechanism never fails, because there is none. I followed Roy Robinson's instructions to make my own: http://coders-log.blogspot.com/2008/10/cat-stove.html

Comment: Nice answer, +1. But I don't find my alcohol stove "finicky to use." It's ridiculously simple. I pour alcohol in the cup. I light it. What I find finicky is my white gas stove, which I never use anymore because it's too much of a pain in the ass.

Comment: @BenCrowell -- What stove do you have?  My alcohol stove works great in 60F+ degree weather.  However 40F and raining was a nightmare.  I'd love to have a better one.

Comment: I don't understand the *must pack out fuel cans* disadvantage.  All fuel comes in containers that must be packed out, except perhaps wood?

Comment: Just wanted to add some since you two revived it: there is a tradeoff between sooty and high density on one side and non sooty, low density and high condensation of water on the other. If you are inside a tent at low temperatures, having a steamy fuel is a major hassle. That aside, taking your stove into the tent is for advanced camping anyways. Not recommended unless you consider the hazards involved.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why gas has issue with altitude. The inside of the canister doesn't care about the outside pressure. Any source for that? (If anything, less pressure means lower evaporation temperature)