# Finding fuel for a Trangia stove in Russia

Tags: fuel, russia

For my [Trangia](https://trangia.se/en/) stove, I usually use denatured alcohol / ethanol / methyl alcohol.  Bringing methyl alcohol into Russia is [apparently prohibited](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/140824/2509), and bringing ethanol is subject to a 22€/litre duty.  I've understood that actually finding *спирт*, as it's apparently called in Russian, is potentially very difficult, according to sources [(1)](http://www.mark-ju.net/juliette/meths.htm), [(2)](https://pikabu.ru/story/gde_kupit_spirt_4284062), [(3)](https://forum.ykt.ru/viewtopic.jsp?id=4323603), [(4)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lada.commerce/wNfr7AzEA30).  One of those sources recommends an industrial site near Moscow and to pay the guard a bit of money for him to get some methyl alcohol...

Where *specifically* can I find fuel for my Trangia stove in Russia?  I will have almost a day in Moscow before I head north to Inta prior to my hike.  I've heard they might sell it at the *аптека*, perhaps in 100 mL bottles.  But I'm also [told](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140784/can-i-bring-methylated-spirits-camping-fuel-into-russia/140824#comment349079_140824) it should be sold at camping stores.  Where can I find a fuel that will be suitable for my stove?

(I will be taking the train, so aviation limitations are not relevant in my case)

Comment: Just a comment because of no actual experience, but this popped up during my search: https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2016/10/04/russian-region-begins-selling-medical-alcohol-from-vending-machines-a55587

Comment: @Jasper unfortunately 70% isn't suitable for a Trangia. It's probably strong enough to burn, but the heat output will be heavily reduced -- not only from the lower alcohol concentration, but from the fact that much of the heat will be wasted heating and evaporating the water. And the burnt sugar/flavouring residues won't do the stove any good. However, it might be worth looking for 95% drinking alcohol (rectified spirits) in shops as a fallback option: probably very expensive compared to denatured alcohol, but still likely to be less than €22 / litre.

Comment: @Pont Also less than the €4 / 100 mL that it might apparently cost at the *аптека*.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative answer in case you can't reliably come up with a good fuel solution: buy an alternative burner for your Trangia stove.

If finding ethanol fuel is too much of a hassle it might be worth considering buying a **gas burner** for the Trangia stove you already have.

See for example [here on the Trangia home page](https://trangia.se/en/selecting-the-right-trangia-stove/).

These burners can be used interchangeably with all modern Trangia stoves, so you could leave the ethanol burner at home and only pack the gas one for this trip.

Comment: Ah, interesting!  Less hassle than buying an entirely new stove (and learning to use it).

Comment: And you won't have to leave the beloved Trangia at home. :) (I know I wouldn't...)

Comment: Looks as though there's also an MSR-style Trangia [multifuel burner](https://trangia.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/780001-multifuel-burner-bayonet-ENG.pdf) (PDF link) which can handle petrol, diesel, and kerosene.

Comment: @Pont I saw that they have spirit, gas, multifuel, and gel burners — I will research the pros and cons of each (I think gas should be easily available in Russia, as of course petrol and diesel)

Comment: I was very happy with my Trangia gas burner, and finding gas is no problem in Russia.  The gas burner has significant advantages to the ethanol burner and I will use it as my preferred burner from now on.