# Fuel for a meths/alcohol stove (trangia) in Russia

Tags: fuel, russia

I have heard on this forum and others the difficulty of finding a suitable fuel since meths is illegal or hard to find, so im trying to think of alternatives, i know Americans use HEET and i have used home brewed vodka before here in NZ ( Moonshine home distilled which it is LEGAL here in NZ to make your own spirits) Just wondering is it possible to find a high enough proof of Vodka in a Hypermarket such as Auchan or Avoska or HEET alternative on the shelf in Russia hypermarkets and the such that could be used as a fuel. Im travelling to Russia ( across it actually ) in 2023 and trying everything i can think of to source on the regular vodka or alternatives to use as fuel for my Trangia BEFORE i invest in a multi fuel stove. Im open to new set up of burner/stove, i just want to try BEFORE i have to invest in new style of cook setup. Does anyone know what Russian Trekkers use. I have seen Decathalon Russia and Sportmaster sell gels, gas and solid fuels burners and fuel which is good.

Also where can you find butane canisters in Russia, i know Decathalon, Sportmaster and Alpinista i think it is called sell them, just wondering if Avoska or Auchan sell them too.

Any ideas anyone? Love to hear them !

EDIT: Current prices for 24 cubes of solid fuel in Russia are about NZD $2 that is 6 times cheaper then NZ so might look in to it as a cooking fuel option. Used solid fuel before too simmer cook ( Have to use a few thou ) so yeah

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding fuel for a Trangia stove in Russia](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22462/finding-fuel-for-a-trangia-stove-in-russia)
Also, see https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20056/what-are-the-different-names-for-and-sources-of-alcohol-for-my-stove and this https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19151/how-are-camping-fuels-named-in-different-languages-and-geographies